# How to avoid code repetition when creating a more complex type that uses the same props with superset types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have two data structures that use "props", where one type of prop is more simple and the other type of prop is more complex. The simple prop type is used for "elements" and the complex one is used for "components".

This is the simple data structure:

```
export interface IPageElementProps {
  maxContainerWidth: number
}

export interface ITextElementProps {
  text: string
  styleRanges: ICanvasTextElementStyleRange[]
}
```

Each of these is then duplicated to allow for a more complicated data structure used by components' props:

```
export interface IPageComponentProps {
  maxContainerWidth: IComponentProp<number>
}

export interface ITextComponentProps {
  text: IComponentProp<string>
  styleRanges: IComponentProp<ICanvasTextElementStyleRange[]>
}

/**
 * A component property defines whether a property is injectable (dynamic)
 * or whether it is hardcoded within the component (non-dynamic or static).
 */
export interface IComponentProp<T> {
  dynamic: boolean
  value?: T
  defaultValue?: T
}
```

Instead of having to redefine each type of element/component (one for the simple data structure and one for the complex one), I would prefer to use a generic type argument. Something along the lines of:

```
export interface IPageProps<T = undefined> {
  maxContainerWidth: T<number>
}
```

Which I would then use for the simple type as simply `props: IPageProps` and for the complex type as `props: IPageProps<IComponentProp>`.

Does this make sense and is there any such feature in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new generic type that will do this for you. The new type will go over all the properties of the given type and "convert" each property to a `IComponentProp`

Like this:

```
export interface IPageElementProps {
  maxContainerWidth: number;
}

export interface ITextElementProps {
  text: string;
  styleRanges: ICanvasTextElementStyleRange[];
}

export interface IComponentProp<T> {
  dynamic: boolean;
  value?: T;
  defaultValue?: T;
}

// This is the magic type
type PageProps<T> = { [P in keyof T]: IComponentProp<T[P]> };

// There new types will do the job
type IPageComponentProps = PageProps<IPageElementProps>;
type ITextComponentProps = PageProps<ITextElementProps>;
```